# Using WHERE in SQL statement on ENUM type breaks mysql_query

Tags: php, mysqli

The Code:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE read=n";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo $row["from_user"], $row["text"];
```

The above code gives me this:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /index.php on line 16
```

The below code does not:

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo $row["from_user"], $row["text"];
```

The "read" field is ENUM('y','n').

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE read='n'";

Comment: @Markedagain Already tried that.  Still returns the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. As it's the name of your column, add backticks surrounding the word in your WHERE clause and that should fix the issue:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE `read` = 'n';
```

Comment: Eff.  I knew it would be something simple.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @cwscribner No problem! Sometimes the PHP/MySQL errors can be a bit cryptic and/or non-constructive. One way to help figure them out is to call `printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));` after the query - it should give you a hint as to where exactly the query's failing (hopefully =P).

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the `ENUM` value, as well as escape `read`, [which is a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE `read` = 'n'";
```